# django.contrib.comments and multiple comment forms

Tags: django

I followed the guide at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/ to set up a comment form on News entries for my current django app. Now, I need to have a comment form with different fields for another type of Object in another part of the site.

How should this be accomplised considering I've overridden the contact form already?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question; django does seem pretty insistent that you use the same comment form everywhere. You can probably write a single form that shows different fields based on the object it's instantiated with. Try writing an **init** method along the lines of this:

```
class CustomCommentForm(CommentForm):
    custom_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # check what's in kwargs['initial'], and insert fields if needed like this:   
        if ...:
            self.fields['optional_field'] = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```